# Law of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Problem states that $$L = \begin{cases}0 ,& with\quad probability\quad 0.75 \\ Z ,& with\quad probability\quad 0.25\end{cases}$$
where $Z\in Exp(\mu)$.

Now, book derives the Law as $F_{L}(x)=0.75+0.25(1-e^{\frac{-x}{\mu}})$.

Here, i recognise the law of an exponential r.v but i do not understand why it is formed like this. I tried to go through the Bernoulli r.v but it did not lead me somewhere.

Any thoughts?

$$L = \begin{cases}0 ,& with\quad probability\quad 0.75 \\ Z ,& with\quad probability\quad 0.25\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\geq0$ then:

$$P(L\leq x)=P(L\leq x\mid L=0)P(L=0)+P(L\leq x\mid L\neq0)P(L\neq0)=$$$$1\times0.75+P(Z\leq x)\times0.25$$